# ImportError: cannot import name 'prepare_dataset' from 'loader'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, loader

I'm having trouble running my code, here are the results of the error I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagger.py", line 8, in <module>
    from loader import prepare_dataset;

ImportError: cannot import name 'prepare_dataset' from 'loader'
```

The following are the related modules installed on my OS.
loader 2017.9.11

If there are other statements that I have not explained, please ask me, and I ask for your help because I have tried to reinstall the module but are still facing the same error, and I apologize if my language is wrong. Thank you ^ - ^

Comment: It seems to me that the `prepare_dataset` module does not exist. Maybe you misspelled the name?

Comment: Are you sure `loader 2017.9.11` is exactly what you need or just guessing?